# Change WildFly 8 welcome-content to use myapplication.war

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, undertow

When using WildFly 8, pointing a browser at `localhost:8080` results in the default `welcome-content` page being displayed.

I want to change this behaviour so that `myapplication.war` is displayed instead.

My `standalone.xml` file currently contains the following default configuration:-

```
<server name="default-server">
  <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
  <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
  </host>
</server>
<handlers>
  <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
</handlers>
```

I have found some posts on the JBossDeveloper Forums that suggest the following:-

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-web-module="name-of-your.war">
```

Just adding the `default-web-module` parameter doesn't seem to work as the `welcome-content` page is still displayed.

Removing the `location` and `filter-ref` items from the `host` section stops the `welcome-content` page being displayed, but results in an HTTP `404 - Not found` error.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the host section to the following and removing the bits described in my original question does in fact work...

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-web-module="name-of-your.war" />
```

I was getting a `404 - Not found` error because of a deployment issue when building the project with NetBeans IDE.

After manually deploying the war file using the WildFly management console, everyting worked just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

We can set the root context in 'jboss-web.xml' under WEB-INF directory.

```
<jboss-web>
 <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

It will overwrite the welcome-content loading.